# How to create a SVG file that is editable in Visio

Tags: java, eclipse, svg, visio, batik

In eclipse GMF editor I am export a diagram as SVG Image but it is not editable in Visio. How can I create an SVG file format that is fully editable in MS-Visio. Is there any method in Java through which I can convert my SVG image to visio editable image??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you just need to load the svg file in visio.

Comment: Correct importing it with Visio and then Select All and Ungroup works......Thanks..